# Load generator in stress testing

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

Is it necessary to have load generator in stress testing. I am stress testing a e-commerce website and in my case I think I don't need run more that 300 virtual users. This amount of users I can run from JMeter non-gui mode. Is this will efficient? Thanks.

Comment: If your estimate concurrent users is 300. What's exactly your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is. You need to "generate the load" from somewhere so you need to have at least one load generator.

If you need only 300 virtual users which can be simulated from a single machine without any issues - you don't need to [run JMeter in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter), most probably **you can generate this load from a single machine**, just make sure to:

- follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- monitor resources consumption like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk IO, pagefile usage, etc. as JMeter needs to have enough headroom to operate in order to be able to send the requests as fast as possible or according to your test scenario. If you don't have better monitoring options in place - you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). The reason for monitoring resources usage by JMeter is that if JMeter cannot send requests fast enough your test results won't be accurate (false-negative) as even if the application has the capacity to handle more load JMeter won't be able to deliver this load if it's configuration isn't suitable or it doesn't have sufficient amount of resources from the operating system

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dmitri. It was really helpful.